# SWT - show multiple table items

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

Could anybody help me?
I have a table in SWT and simply I want to show some table items but the table only shows one item and the others with vertical scroll. I want to show everything, without scrolling. I tried with the option SWT_NO_SCROLL but is not working. I have a method that creates the table and other that populates it creating a new table item, they´re working good, the problem is that only shows the first item and the other are scrolling.

My code is:

```
private void createTable(Composite parent){

    table = new Table (parent, SWT.BORDER);

    TableColumn tcFile = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    TableColumn tcStatus = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);

    tcFile.setText("File");
    tcStatus.setText("Status");

    tcFile.setWidth(500);
    tcStatus.setWidth(500);

    table.setVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
}

private void populateTable(String file, String status){
    TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.LEFT);
    item.setText(new String[] { file, status});

}


Composite top = new Composite(parent, SWT.WRAP);
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
layout.marginHeight = -5;
layout.marginWidth = 0;
top.setLayout(layout);

Composite banner = new Composite(top, SWT.WRAP);

banner.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING, false, false));
layout = new GridLayout();
layout.marginHeight = 0;
layout.marginWidth = 10;
layout.numColumns = 5;
banner.setLayout(layout);

createTable(top);
```

Comment: How are you setting the vertical size of the Table? Are you using a Layout, or setBounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified any layout data for the `Table`, try something like:

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
table.setLayoutData(data);
```

If you don't have anything else that is setting the dialog/window size you may need to specify a table height hint:

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
data.heightHint = 200;  // Vertical size for table
table.setLayoutData(data);
```

Comment: Greg! you are a genius! I didn´t realized that that code was missing. I´m new in SWT and Java in general, so I have too much to learn. Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: Excuse me Greg, I´ve seen you have a lot of experience in RCP /SWT applications, do you know if is very difficult to create a toolbar with 3 perspectives shortcut that can be available to switch when I open the application? because I can´t find much information about SWT.

Comment: SWT is just the low level controls. Perspectives are Eclipse RCP features